# PostgreSQL - to_timestamp is not properly converting unix timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I'm trying to get current UTC time, and insert it into PostgreSQL timestamp. But it's not working properly.

I am using the following command:

```
INSERT INTO public.rt_block_height 
VALUES(to_timestamp('2018-09-09 00:36:00.778653', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.MS.US'), 83.7)
```

However, when I check the result, it looks like this:

```
tutorial=# select * from rt_block_height;
          time           | block_height
-------------------------+--------------
 2018-09-09 00:48:58.653 |         83.7
(1 row)
```

I don't know what's causing this mismatch.

FYI, here my source code for table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.rt_BLOCK_HEIGHT
(
"time" timestamp without time zone,
BLOCK_HEIGHT double precision
)
WITH (
OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.rt_BLOCK_HEIGHT
OWNER to postgres;
SELECT create_hypertable('rt_BLOCK_HEIGHT', 'time');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a logical error in the format string as you should not use `MS` and `US` at the same time. However, you do not need the function at all, just cast the string to `timestamp`:

```
INSERT INTO public.rt_block_height 
VALUES('2018-09-09 00:36:00.778653'::timestamp, 83.7)
```

From [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)

> `to_timestamp` and `to_date` exist to handle input formats that cannot be converted by simple casting. For most standard date/time formats, simply casting the source string to the required data type works, and is much easier.